# Vue event when open PWA on mobile from the background

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, progressive-web-apps

I have a Vue application that's used as PWA (added to homescreen on mobile).

Everything works fine but I have one issue:  When somebody sends the app to the background, and after some minutes opens the same app again, but some data may have changed in the last minutes.

Does Vue have any event to handle reopening? Because I need to check (call API) whether the database has new items?

Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Yes, of course, you have to look at the caching strategies Vue or in my case Nuxt JS. There you create a strategy that either serves the cache first (Old saved data) or you can make API calls every x amount of time. Can't give you an example since I work with Nuxt, but shouldn't be too hard to figure out with Vue itself

Comment: @Luka can you explain it for me please? at this moment not too clear for me what you wrote.